# How can I remove this popup from TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

How can I remove this popup if I use the free version?

[image]

No clue how to remove it. Please suggest.

Comment: Please add the relevant code. [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.